# How to create space between containers created using for-loop

Tags: flutter, dart, for-loop, containers

I kinda have this problem where I want to add space or a sized box between the containers I have made but the thing is I made using a for-loop and have no idea how to do that. Here's my code and thank you so much in advance...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BlogPost extends StatelessWidget {
  const BlogPost({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            Container(
              width: 150,
              height: 180,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF).withOpacity(0.1),
                borderRadius:
                    const BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(35.0, 35.0)),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `padding` property. For example

```dart
Container(
  width: 150,
  height: 180,  
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), // <-- See this
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF).withOpacity(0.1),
    borderRadius:
    const BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(35.0, 35.0)),
  ),
),
```

You can find more properties on their documentation at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks but the problem isn't solved yet

Comment: please share your code and what you see